# Return false not working and action gets triggered on click of h:commandButton

Tags: javascript, jsf

I have an issue when return false is executed still the action takes place. I don't understand what the issue is.

```
<h:commandButton value="Deny" style="margin-left: 5px;" id="button"                     
action="#{myController.submitRequest('deny', 'return')}"
onclick="javascript:statusCheck();"/>
```

JS Code:

```
function statusCheck()
                {
                    var msgArray = [];
                    var validate = true;
                    var status=  document.getElementById('userValue:statusId');

                    if(status.value.trim() == "")
                    {
                        msgArray.push("Status required");
                        alert("check");
                        validate = false;
                    }
                    alert("after check");
                    alert(validate);
                    if(validate) {
                        return true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                      if(msgArray.length >0)
                      {
                            alert(msgArray.join('\n'));
                            alert("test");
                            return false;
                      }
                    }   
                }
```

Now in the above JS function i can clearly see the alert test gets called but still the action is triggered. Please guide.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should actually **return** something from the javascript that is inside the `onclick` attribute.

So changing

```
onclick="javascript:statusCheck()"
```

to

```
onclick="return statusCheck()"
```

should do the trick. I've seen before that it is (sometimes?) actually needed to return something from the statement in the onclick. The fact that the function that is called (`statusCheck()`) returns something does not mean this return value is also returned further to the commandButton onclick. So it always continues to call the action

Comment: Wonderful explaination !